# how to access $user from commandline?

Tags: 7, users, drush

I'd like to access $user from the commandline to see what properties are available on it.  I could `sdpm($user)` in my code and go inspect it in my browser, but isn't there a way I can inspect it right from my terminal?

It looks like `drush php` could be helpful here, according to http://blog.damiankloip.net/2015/drush-php, but when I use it and do `dump -a $user` I get 'Unknown variable: $user'.  That's probably obvious, so I probably need to load $user into the repl first (I'm guessing)... but how?  That blog post shows how to load objects in D8, but how would I do this in D7 for $user???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the $user variable first. You can run the drush command as a particular user by specifying --user on the command line:

```
drush --user='admin' ev 'global $user; print_r($user);'
```

If you don't specify a user, drush runs as anonymous by default.

Or, you can do it like this:

```
drush ev '$user = user_load_by_name("admin"); print_r($user);'
```

It will display this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [uid] => 1
    [name] => admin
    [pass] => *****
    [mail] => info@example.com
    [theme] => 
    [signature] => 
    [signature_format] => filtered_html
    [created] => 1443708895
    [access] => 1515415027
    [login] => 1515411954
    [status] => 1
    [timezone] => Europe/London
    [language] => 
    [picture] => 0
    [init] => info@example.com
    [data] => 
    [uuid] => f6800524-c092-4abc-abcd-f71d091623cd
    [roles] => Array
        (
            [2] => authenticated user
        )

    [force_password_change] => 0
)
```

Comment: Excellent, and the second option was what I needed to get it to work in the repl with `drush php`.  Thanks!